# How to speed up simple query

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6 and have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE eco.tracks ( 
    id                   bigserial  NOT NULL,
    time_track           timestamp  NOT NULL,
    track                bigint  ,
    distance_1             int  ,

    CONSTRAINT pk_tracks PRIMARY KEY ( id )
 );
```

And I manipulate data it contains with a very simple query:

```
  SELECT (track, distance_1, time_track) 
    FROM eco.tracks 
   WHERE time_track - (%s) <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds' 
     AND (%s)-time_track <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds' 
     AND distance_1 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY distance_1 asc LIMIT 1;
```

Some inputs:

```
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (23467, '2018-05-18 20:43:06', 386, 17965);
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (23468, '2018-05-18 20:43:07', 386, 18168);
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (23469, '2018-05-18 20:43:08', 386, 18168);
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (22974, '2018-05-18 20:40:07', 376, 8394);
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (22968, '2018-05-18 20:40:00', 376, 9051);
INSERT INTO tracks (id, time_track, track, distance_1) VALUES (22837, '2018-05-18 20:39:17', 366, 13133);
```

This query is used to take the closest track number & other two params  in range of setted time +- 10sec. But in my system, this one is a bottleneck, is it possible to improve it?

I've tried to play around with value `work_mem`, no success.

Actually, I use it for checking like if-else. And then make another query.
Can I merge it?

```
    SELECT (track, distance_1, aircraft_time)
      FROM eco.tracks WHERE time_track - (%s) <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds' and (%s)-time_track <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds'  ORDER BY distance_1 asc LIMIT 1,
    CASE track WHEN NOT NULL THEN
    (
    INSERT INTO eco.noise (
    time_noise, track, distance, aircraft_time)
      VALUES (%s, track, distance_1, aircraft_time) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
    )

    OR

 WITH check_1 AS
  (SELECT track, distance_1, aircraft_time FROM eco.tracks
 WHERE time_track - (%s) <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds' and (%s)-time_track <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds'  ORDER BY distance_1 asc LIMIT 1)
 INSERT INTO eco.noise (time_noise, track, distance, aircraft_time)
  VALUES (%s, check_1.track, check_1.distance_1, check_1.aircraft_time) 
 WHERE
 check_1.track IS NOT NULL ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
                )
```

---

<sub>*Note*: I use it in Python 3 by using psycopg2.</sub>

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not put the columns in the select list between parentheses. `select (track, distance_1, time_track)` returns a single column that is an anonymous record with multiple fields. `select track, distance_1, time_track` returns multiple columns

Comment: Try to change `time_track - (%s) <=  INTERVAL '10 seconds'` to `time_track  <= (%s) +  INTERVAL '10 seconds'` so indexes can be used. And similarly for the other conditiion.

Comment: what's that bit at the end with "case" for... the syntax looks bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have an index on time_track

move the offsets to the other side of the inequality so that the arithmetic is only done once and so that an index on time_track can be used.

```
SELECT (track, distance_1, aircraft_time)
  FROM eco.tracks 
  WHERE time_track >= (%s) + INTERVAL '10 seconds'
    and time_track <= (%s) - INTERVAL '10 seconds'
ORDER BY distance_1 asc LIMIT 1,
```

etc...

or you could use `BETWEEN` instead of and.

```
SELECT (track, distance_1, aircraft_time)
  FROM eco.tracks 
  WHERE time_track BETWEEN
        (%s) - INTERVAL '10 seconds'
    AND (%s) + INTERVAL '10 seconds'
ORDER BY distance_1 asc LIMIT 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the time interval in the application and use a query like:

```
SELECT (track, distance_1, time_track) 
FROM tracks 
WHERE time_track BETWEEN (%s) AND (%s)
  AND distance_1 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY distance_1 asc
LIMIT 1;
```

An index like:

```
CREATE INDEX ... (time_track, distance_1, track) ON tracks
```

will help

Comment: you can. so long as the application understands time the same as postgres. eg:timestamps are discontinuous at the ends of daylight savings

Comment: i don't see a reason to index time_track twice in the same index, or how distance_1 would help, unless the timestamps are very clumpy.

Comment: distance_1 is used in the order by clause, it may help to find the first row

Comment: it wont help because you're taking a range of time_track.  with two separate indexes it could do a bitmap thing if there are enough results, but there probably aren't.